# New to WP: links on static homepage are not working

Tags: customization, urls, links, homepage

I am new to WP. 
In our Twenty Seventeen Child template, I have a page that I use as a static homepage. On this page I have created links.  The links are displayed underlined and in the source code of the page, I see the correct url.
However, the links do not work. I cannot click them and when I hover they do not change color.
  When I copy the same page and give it a different name, the links are working. When I set the copied page as a homepage, links are dead again.
I guess it has something to do with the homepage static setting.
Can anybody tell me how to have a static page with the links working correctly?

Comment: possibly to do with z-index in the CSS; please ask in https://wordpress.org/support/theme/twentyseventeen; you might need to provide a link to your site.

Comment: I have tested that. And you appear to be 100% right!! That is some good thinking you did there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide inks so we can see the code? If you ust need simple links just use the vidual design mode and use hyperlink... or do it in html. To make a hyperlink in an HTML page, use the  and  tags, which are the tags used to define the links. The  tag indicates where the hyperlink starts and the  tag indicates where it ends. Whatever text gets added inside these tags, will work as a hyperlink. Add the URL for the link in the .

Comment: It appears to be the z-index as @Michael suggested.